# How to drag form child element to parent

Tags: jquery, draggable, drag

I have html:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child-parent">
       <div class="child"></div>
       <div class="child"></div>
       <div class="child"></div>
       <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is photo: http://iv.pl/images/77948798984235036424.png

How Can I drag child element from child-parent div to div id="parent"
Now, I have: http://www.iv.pl/images/74542421998386458835.png

I forgot I have jquery-draggable script

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
 $(".child-parent").children().appendTo("#parent");
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JKq8f/)**